# FreeBSD rsync server: please follow symlinks in target directory

Tags: backup, rsync, symbolic-link, freebsd

**Summary**

rsync server on FreeBSD won't follow local symlinks to dirs. It will either error out (can't write file) or clobber the symlink and create an actual directory, which is not the desired behavior.

**Background**

I have two Windows machines. The first - let's call it Newfs - is basically a file server. Newfs inherited all of its disks, except the boot disk, from another machine - let's call this Oldfs. Oldfs still has its old boot disk, while all the other disks are now network disks mapped from Newfs with the same drive letters they used to have.

So, from a Windows point of view, except for their boot drives C, Newfs and Oldfs have the same disks with the same drive letters (D, E, etc); only, the disks are network disks on Oldfs and physical disks on Newfs.

**The Problem**

I'm using an rsync server on a FreeBSD-based NAS to backup my Windows boxes. It has separate modules (basically, target directories) for each machine being backed up. I created a new module for Newfs and made a `/backup/Newfs/C` directory on the NAS backup server for the new boot disk. Then I made symlinks to the existing directories:

```
/backup/Newfs/D --> ../Oldfs/D
/backup/Newfs/E --> ../Oldfs/E
```

This was done so I could launch rsync both from Oldfs and Newfs without mixing up the backups of their respective C drives.

Unfortunately, the links themselves work fine if I follow them with a shell running on the NAS, but apparently the rsync server doesn't do what I would like it to do. I would like separate backup paths for Newfs and Oldfs, actually leading into the same actual directory for e.g. the D drive, without duplicated files. Symlinks as I set them up don't work. Is there some option I'm overlooking? Searching only yielded results about following/copying symlinks on the sources, not on the destination.

Comment: I found out about the --keep-dirlinks option, short form -K. I just don't think it's implemented on FreeBSD. Server ignores the option, so it either (a) clobbers soft link to directories into real directories, and goes on to happily copy files, or (b) fails because it can't clobber a link because of permissions. No solution yet.

Comment: I think I either misunderstood the -K, --keep-dirlinks option, or it simply doesn't work on FreeBSD (where my rsync server lives). Still waiting for someone to shed some light.